# psychopy reset variable for each trial

Tags: python, timeline, psychopy

I made my own rating scale, which is a timeline from 0 to 28:18. It moves according to how fast people press the 't' or 'b' keys for each trial. What comes up on the screen looks like this:

[image: experiment]

I want the time at the top to reset to 14:09 for each trial. After each trial is a 0.5 second inter trial interval during which a '+' is presented on the screen. The problem I'm having is that if you press 't' or 'b' during the ITI, the next trial won't start at 14:09. Instead, it will be shifted by the direction in which a 't' or 'b' press shifts the timeline. Here's my current code where I tried to correct for this:

```
prevPos = 0
trialNum=0
b_list=[]
t_list=[]
key=[]

# loop through pictures
for eachPic in catPictures:
    b_list=[]
    t_list=[]
    timer = core.CountdownTimer(TrialDuration)
    while timer.getTime() > 0:
        for key in event.getKeys():
            if key in ['escape']:
                core.quit() # quit if they press escape
            if key in ['b']:
                # add keypress to list for each keypress. then move cursor proportionally to length of this list
                b_list.append(key)
                prevPos+=len(b_list)
            if key in ['t']:
                t_list.append(key)
                prevPos-=len(t_list)

    # set upper and lower limits to where cursor can go (which will later be halved to restrict range of cursor on the screen)
        if prevPos <= -849:
            prevPos = -849
        elif prevPos >=849:
            prevPos = 849
        # make absolute position so pos_absolute becomes a range from 0 to 300 (based on 28:18 min movie)
        pos_absolute = prevPos + 849
        # need to have range of 1698 (# of seconds in 28:18)
        # need to have range of 1698 (# of seconds in 28:18)
        # current range is 0 to 849 (which is 50% of 1698)
        seconds =  pos_absolute

        Image2 = visual.ImageStim(window)
        #curbImage2.setSize = ((0.5,0.5), units = 'norm')
        # make a little higher than the absolute middle
        Image2.setPos([0,100])
        # use each image (i in curbImages)
        Image2.setImage(catPictures[trialNum])

        # define cursor that moves along timeline
        cursorImage = visual.ImageStim(window)
        cursorImage.setImage(directoryStim+'cursor.png')
        # make cursor move by however big prevPos is
        cursorImage.setPos([int(prevPos)*.5,int(400)])
        # make the line
        timeline = visual.SimpleImageStim(win=window, image=directoryStim+'line.png', units='pix', pos=[0, 400])
    event.clearEvents() # get rid of other, unprocessed events

        # print min and max values next to timeline
        min = visual.TextStim(window, '0:00', color='Black', pos=[-500, 400])
        max = visual.TextStim(window, '28:18', color='Black', pos=[500, 400])
        # print constantly updating time value
        timeText = visual.TextStim(window,'%d:%02d' % (seconds/60, seconds % 60),color='Black',wrapWidth=1080,font='Verdana', pos=[0,465], height=50)

        ## now put everything on the screen
        Image2.draw(window)
        min.draw(window)
        max.draw(window)
        timeText.draw(window)
        timeline.draw(window)
        cursorImage.draw(window)
    ## flip so it actually appears
        window.flip()

    ITI = visual.TextStim(window, '+', pos=[0,0], height=50, color='Black')
    ITI.draw(window)
    window.flip()
    core.wait(.5,.5)
    trialNum+=1
    prevPos = 0
    b_list =[]
    t_list=[]
    key=[]
```

How can I make my timeline reset to 14:09 (aka `prevPos` = 0) at the beginning of each trial, even if people press 't' or 'b' as the trial ends or during the inter trial interval?

Comment: Could you take another look at your indentation?

Comment: Throughout, you are re-creating objects on each iteration of the loop. This is time-inefficient (it takes a lot longer to initialise an object than it does to update its attributes). e.g. `timer = core.CountdownTimer(TrialDuration)` should occur at the top of the code, and in its current location, just have the line `timer.reset()`. Similarly, shift the creation of each image e.g. `Image2 = visual.ImageStim(window)`, to the top of the code, and inside the loop, you only need  `Image2.setImage(catPictures[trialNum])`. The other images are constant, so should only be created once.

Comment: Plus one for the kitteh. You know how to grab internet's attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Indent stuff under the inner for-loop.
2. Move your `event.clearEvents()` to just before your `while`-loop
   or after the `core.wait`. That's where you start listening for new
   key presses. Presses during the wait-period will be returned on the
   next call to `event.getKeys()` in the next cycle of the
   while-loop. That's why it moves the cursor immediately. There's no
   real reason to have the `event.clearEvents()` where you have it
   since you only listen for events in the while-loop. That's why I
   suggest that you move it rather than inserting a new one.
3. Initiating psychopy stimuli is quite reseource-heavy
   and can sometimes take several hundred milliseconds. There's no
   reason to create several new `ImageStims` and `TextStims` on
   each trial.
4. `pos_absolute` and `seconds` are redundant. You could do with only `seconds`.
5. A style-thing: rather than `stim.setPos(x)` you can now do `stim.pos = x` and so on for all other attributes. This is the preferred way to set stimulus attributes from now on (cleaner code and allows for more operations on the attributes).

Here's a cleaned up code with the above changes:

```
# Stimuli
Image2 = visual.ImageStim(window)
cursorImage = visual.ImageStim(window)
min = visual.TextStim(window, '0:00', color='Black', pos=[-500, 400])
max = visual.TextStim(window, '28:18', color='Black', pos=[500, 400])
timeText = visual.TextStim(window,color='Black',wrapWidth=1080,font='Verdana', pos=[0,465], height=50)
ITI = visual.TextStim(window, '+', pos=[0,0], height=50, color='Black')
timeline = visual.SimpleImageStim(win=window, image=directoryStim+'line.png', units='pix', pos=[0, 400])
timer = core.CountdownTimer(TrialDuration)

# loop through pictures
trialNum=0
for eachPic in catPictures:
    prevPos = 0
    key=[]
    b_list=[]
    t_list=[]
    timer.reset()
    event.clearEvents() # get rid of other, unprocessed events
    while timer.getTime() > 0:
        for key in event.getKeys():
            if key in ['escape']:
                core.quit() # quit if they press escape
            if key in ['b']:
                # add keypress to list for each keypress. then move cursor proportionally to length of this list
                b_list.append(key)
                prevPos+=len(b_list)
            if key in ['t']:
                t_list.append(key)
                prevPos-=len(t_list)

        # set upper and lower limits to where cursor can go (which will later be halved to restrict range of cursor on the screen)
        if prevPos <= -849:
            prevPos = -849
        elif prevPos >=849:
            prevPos = 849
        # make absolute position so pos_absolute becomes a range from 0 to 300 (based on 28:18 min movie)
        # need to have range of 1698 (# of seconds in 28:18)
        # need to have range of 1698 (# of seconds in 28:18)
        # current range is 0 to 849 (which is 50% of 1698)
        seconds =  prevPos + 849

        #curbImage2.size = ((0.5,0.5), units = 'norm')
        # make a little higher than the absolute middle
        Image2.pos = [0,100]
        # use each image (i in curbImages)
        Image2.image = catPictures[trialNum]

        # define cursor that moves along timeline
        cursorImage.image = directoryStim+'cursor.png'
        # make cursor move by however big prevPos is
        cursorImage.pos = [int(prevPos)*.5,int(400)]
        timeText.text = '%d:%02d' % (seconds/60, seconds % 60))

        ## now put everything on the screen
        Image2.draw(window)
        min.draw(window)
        max.draw(window)
        timeText.draw(window)
        timeline.draw(window)
        cursorImage.draw(window)
        ## flip so it actually appears
        window.flip()

    ITI.draw(window)
    window.flip()
    core.wait(.5,.5)
    trialNum+=1
```

Notice that I also removed several seemingly unnecessary resets of `b_list`, `key` etc.

Comment: awesome, thanks!! FYI the only things I had to change to make it work were to indent the for loop after the while loop (until the ITI section. this was my bad in the original code) and remove  parentheses from where you define `timeText`. you cleaned it up quite a bit, thanks!

Comment: Cool. I forgot to move ``timeline`` and ``timer``. I updated the answer code with that. Also indented the inner for-loop. See also the new point 4 and 5 with a few more suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

In the last line of the code, try this:

`event.clearEvents()`

Keys being pressed during your ITI are going into a buffer and so will be collected the next time you call `event.getKeys()`. By calling `clearEvents()`, you flush that buffer.